# JavaFX 8 - How to bind TextField text property to TableView integer property

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Let's say I have a situation like this: I have a `TableView` (tableAuthors) with two `TableColumns` (Id and Name).

This is the AuthorProps POJO which is used by `TableView`:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;


public class AuthorProps {
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty authorsId;
    private final SimpleStringProperty authorsName;


    public AuthorProps(int authorsId, String authorsName) {
        this.authorsId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(authorsId);
        this.authorsName = new SimpleStringProperty( authorsName);
    }

    public int getAuthorsId() {
        return authorsId.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty authorsIdProperty() {
        return authorsId;
    }

    public void setAuthorsId(int authorsId) {
        this.authorsId.set(authorsId);
    }

    public String getAuthorsName() {
        return authorsName.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty authorsNameProperty() {
        return authorsName;
    }

    public void setAuthorsName(String authorsName) {
        this.authorsName.set(authorsName);
    }
}
```

And let's say I have two `TextFields` (txtId and txtName). Now, I would like to bind values from table cells to `TextFields`.

```
 tableAuthors.getSelectionModel()
                .selectedItemProperty()
                .addListener((observableValue, authorProps, authorProps2) -> {
                    //This works:
                    txtName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(authorProps2.authorsNameProperty());
                    //This doesn't work:
                    txtId.textProperty().bindBidirectional(authorProps2.authorsIdProperty());
                });
```

I can bind Name `TableColumn` to txtName `TextField` because `authorsNameProperty` is a `SimpleStringProperty`, but I can't bind Id `TableColumn` to txtId `TextField` because `authorsIdProperty` is a `SimpleIntegerProperty`. My question is: How can I bind txtId to Id `TableColumn`?

P.S. I can provide working example if it's necessary.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
txtId.textProperty().bindBidirectional(authorProps2.authorsIdProperty(), new NumberStringConverter());
```

Comment: @Hendrikto Try `txtId.textProperty().bind(authorProps2.authorsIdProperty().asString())`

Comment: @James_D I want to bind an IntegerProperty to a TextField though. Excactly the opposite of that.

Comment: Use [`Bindings.createIntegerBinding(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createIntegerBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-)