# JavaFX - How to set value to a textfield inside a tab?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to set value to a text field which is inside a Tab. I am having multiple tabs and I want to set value to text field inside each tab.
Any idea as to how to set the text for textfield inside the tab?
I am using the below code to update the value for the textfield, but nothing's happening while trying to do the same.

**Code:**

```
public class FXMLController {
    @FXML
    private Button inputXmlFileBtn;
    @FXML
    private TextField inputXmlName;
    @FXML
    private TabPane xmlData;
    @FXML
    private Tab vendorHeaderFb;
    @FXML
    private TextField vendorHeader1;
    Label label;

    public String inputXmlFileChooser() throws ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, IOException, JAXBException {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        // Set extension filter
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new ExtensionFilter("XML files (*.xml)", "*.xml"));

        // Open Dialog
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        String xmlPath = "";
        xmlPath = file.getPath();

        // Set the path for inputXmlName text field
        if (file != null) {
            inputXmlName.setText(xmlPath);
        }

        //Unmarshall
        label = this.unmarshallXml();
        System.out.println(label.getVendorHeader1());
        vendorHeaderFb = new Tab();
        vendorHeader1 = new TextField();
        vendorHeader1.setText(label.getVendorHeader1());
        vendorHeaderFb.setContent(vendorHeader1);
        return xmlPath;
    }
```

**Updated Code including the Pojo class for FXML.**

```
public class FXMLController {
    @FXML
    private Button inputXmlFileBtn;
    @FXML
    private TextField inputXmlName;
    @FXML
    private TabPane xmlData;
    @FXML
    private Tab vendorHeaderFb;
    @FXML
    private TextField VendorHeader1;
    Label label;

    public String inputXmlFileChooser() throws ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, IOException, JAXBException {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        // Set extension filter
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new ExtensionFilter("XML files (*.xml)", "*.xml"));

        // Open Dialog
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        String xmlPath = "";
        xmlPath = file.getPath();

        // Set the path for inputXmlName text field
        if (file != null) {
            inputXmlName.setText(xmlPath);
        }

        //Unmarshall
        label = this.unmarshallXml();
        System.out.println(label.getVendorHeader1());
        FXMLProps fxmlProps = new FXMLProps();
        fxmlProps.setVendorHeader1(label.getVendorHeader1());
        System.out.println(fxmlProps.getVendorHeader1());
        VendorHeader1 = new TextField();
        VendorHeader1.setText(fxmlProps.getVendorHeader1());
        //vendorHeaderFb.setContent(vendorHeader1);
        //vendorHeader1.setText(label.getVendorHeader1());
        //vendorHeaderFb.setContent(vendorHeader1);


        return xmlPath;
    }
```

**POJO/Property Class**

```
public class FXMLProps {
    private final SimpleStringProperty VendorHeader1 = new SimpleStringProperty(
            "");

    public FXMLProps() {
    }

    public FXMLProps(String VendorHeader1) {
        setVendorHeader1(VendorHeader1);
    }

    public String getVendorHeader1() {
        return VendorHeader1.get();
    }

    public void setVendorHeader1(String vH1) {
        VendorHeader1.set(vH1);
    }
}
```

I am still not able to set the value for text field vendorHeader1. 
Can someone point out what's going wrong?

Comment: You could create a text property and bind all the `TextField` values to it. Then just alter the property. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622636/javafx-8-how-to-bind-textfield-text-property-to-tableview-integer-property

Comment: @deHaar Thanks! But can you add some code snippet for the same? I am new to using Tabs.

Comment: There are code snippets in the link and you can look for `Binding`, `Property` and `TextField` at stackoverflow as well as everywhere else. Forget about those `Tabs`, you only need to bind (each) `TextField`'s text property to the property for the text value. Those properties are very similar to regular class attributes. I just don't have time now for an example... Try something and post it here when errors or questions come up.

Comment: Nothing happens since you don't do anything with the tab with the textfield you just created. Replacing the value in a field, even in one that is annotated with `@FXML`, does nothing to the new and/or old value. You still need to add the tab to the tabpane. BTW: Beware of `NullPointerExceptions`: `file.getPath(); if (file != null) {`

Comment: @deHaar I have updated the code with Property Class. I am able to print the value of VendorHeader1 in console but when I try setting the value for the textfiled, it doesn't happen so.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply a `Binding` between the text property of the `TextField` and the `SimpleStringProperty` that is used for the value. You will have to make the vendor header property of your `FXMLProps` public in a way that enables `Binding` options in other classes:

```
public class FXMLProps {

    private final SimpleStringProperty vendorHeader = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public FXMLProps() {}

    public FXMLProps(String vendorHeader) {
        setVendorHeader(vendorHeader);
    }

    public String getVendorHeader() {
        return VendorHeader1.get();
    }

    public void setVendorHeader(String vendorHeaderText) {
        vendorHeader.set(vendorHeaderText);
    }

    // this is needed for the Binding
    public final SimpleStringProperty vendorHeaderProperty() {
        return vendorHeader;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your application (maybe in `start()`) you need to create the `Binding` like

```
// bind those two properties (TextField, SimpleStringProperty)
Bindings.bindBidirectional(vendorHeader1.textProperty(), fxmlProps.vendorHeaderProperty());
```